# How to properly reference a checkbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to determine the value of a checkbox. Why does the first JS example not work, but the second does?

CSHTML

```
<div style="border-style: solid;">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.paios)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.paios)
</div>
```

JS

```
console.log($('#paios').checked); //UNDEFINED

$('#paios').change(function () {
    console.log(this.checked); //returns true or false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `checked` is an Element property, and jQuery does not directly expose Element properties.  You have to use the accessory methods.

```
$('#paios').prop('checked')
//or break the Element out of the jQuery object
$('#paios')[0].checked
```